# How can I create and use Linux cgroups as a non-root user?

Tags: linux, cgroup

How can I create and use [cgroups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) as a non-root user?

For example, can I, entirely as a non-root user:

- create a cgroup with access to one CPU
- create a new process in that cgroup

?

I first asked [here](http://lists2.linuxjournal.com/pipermail/linux-list/2013-February/031811.html) but I didn't receive a complete answer. I also [asked on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864735/how-can-i-create-and-use-linux-cgroups-as-a-non-root-user), but the question was closed as off topic.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't do that as a normal user. But you can setup a cgroup as root, and make it configurable by your user.

If you do not already have the default cgroups controllers mounted by e.g. systemd:

```
$ sudo mount -t tmpfs cgroup_root /sys/fs/cgroup
$ sudo mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset
$ sudo mount -t cgroup -o cpuset cpuset /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset
```

Create a cgroup:

```
$ sudo mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/${USER}
$ sudo chown -R ${USER} /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/${USER}
```

You can now modify the configuration of your cgroup as a normal user:

```
$ echo 0-3 > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/${USER}/cpuset.cpus
```

Add a process to that group:

```
$ ./my_task &
$ echo $! > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/${USER}/tasks
```

Or create a subgroup:

```
$ mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/${USER}/subgroup
$ echo 0-1 > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/${USER}/subgroup/cpuset.cpus
$ ./my_other_task &
$ echo $! > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/${USER}/subgroup/tasks
```

Comment: how would you delete the subgroup? `rm -r` fails for me

Comment: `rm -r` would try to delete the files first, which fails. Use `rmdir` to remove a cgroup.

Comment: You cannot `rmdir` until the `tasks` file is empty. root would need to look at the tasks file in the subgroup, and echo each pid there into the root cgroup's tasks file (`/dev/cpuset/tasks` on my RHEL 6.7 [kernel 2.6.32-358] box, but it looks like `/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/tasks` might by appropriate here).

Answer (score 2):

If you have recent enough Linux distribution you should be able to run processes in transient (temporary) cgroups, e.g.

```
$ systemd-run --user --scope /bin/bash
```

However, `systemd` is broken in <strike>many Linux  distributions</strike> all Ubuntu variants prior version release 21.10 and then the above fails with something like

```
polkitd(authority=local)[1300]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:10428:26722972 (system bus name :1.478 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_DK.utf8)
systemd[2601]: run-rbe547d13ad2c41d7857ea9e660e51ab9.scope: Failed to add PIDs to scope's control group: Permission denied
systemd[2601]: run-rbe547d13ad2c41d7857ea9e660e51ab9.scope: Failed with result 'resources'.
systemd[2601]: Failed to start /bin/bash.
polkitd(authority=local)[1300]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:10428:26722972 (system bus name :1.478, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_DK.utf8) (disconnected from bus)
```

The reason for this failure is that running transient cgroups without root requires support for `cgroupv2` / `cgroup2` but Canonical really wants to push `snap`. And using `cgroup2` would have broken `snap` until the `snap` had been patch enough. Ubuntu 21.10 is the first Ubuntu release that has smart enough `snap` to work with `cgroup2` so any older Ubuntu version is intentionally broken for transient cgroups to allow `snap` to run at all.

I guess distributions that do not even try to support the misfeature called `snap` will have much less problems supporting `cgroup2` and this should work with older distribution versions, too.

If `mount | grep cgroup2` outputs anything, your system is recent enough.

Comment: Interesting. What distributions did this fail on?

Comment: I'm currently running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I know it used to fail with older versions, too, but I haven't tested if it works in more recent version. It appears that it's missing fixes to bug https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/9512 – note that without `sudo` you probably don't want `--scope` but `--pty`.

Comment: Works for me on 248, no sudo or --pty needed. I wonder why Ubuntu hasn't backported it? Did nobody open a bug in launchpad?

Comment: It seems that the problem was the hack called `snap` by Canonical. It didn't support `cgroupv2` until recently so Ubuntu postponed the switch until `snap` could work with newer API. This should work with Ubuntu 21.10 or greater according to documentation.

Comment: If `mount | grep cgroupv2` outputs something, you're running recent enough system.

Comment: OMG! thank you for the clarification! its clear now!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Ubuntu you (the root user) can install **cgroup-lite** and add what you need to /etc/cgconfig.conf, including which user(s) can change the cgroup's configuration. It runs on boot.

Failing that you (the root user) could add your own script to run during boot.

Answer (score 0):

There is a series of articles on [LWN](http://lwn.net) on cgroups, see [part 1](http://lwn.net/Articles/531114/), or look though the search there. [Systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd) includes a set of helpers to manage (processes caged by) cgroups.

Comment: That link for part 1 should probably point to https://lwn.net/Articles/531114 instead.

Comment: The linked LWN article is about namespaces, https://lwn.net/Articles/604609/ is about cgroups.